# Sending data from C# program to Arduino

Tags: c#, arduino

I have a problem with sending numbers from the C# prog to the Arduino (one value at the time).
I noticed that if I send value lower than 128 its ok, the problems started with higher values.

**C# lines:**

```
shinput = Convert.ToInt16(line2); // shinput = short.
byte[] bytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(shinput);
arduino.Write(bytes, 0, 2);
```

**Arduino lines:**

```
Serial.readBytes(reciver,2);
inByte[counter]= reciver[0]+(reciver[1]*256);
```

I will really appreciate any help.

Comment: Is your C# program and the arduino code transmitting at the same baud?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to test with known values to ensure proper communication, in a known order;

```
arduino.Write(new byte[]{ 145}, 0, 1);
arduino.Write(new byte[]{ 240}, 0, 1);
```

then

```
Serial.readBytes(reciver,1); //check reciver == 145
Serial.readBytes(reciver,1); //check reciver == 240
```

Assuming this is correct, now test the Endianness

```
arduino.Write(new byte[]{ 145, 240}, 0, 2);
```

then

```
Serial.readBytes(reciver,1); //check reciver == 145
Serial.readBytes(reciver,1); //check reciver == 240
```

in the end it may well be that you have a byte reciver[1] * 256 and you need to cast it up to a value that can store the larger value:

```
((int) reciver[1] * 256)
```

so try this:

```
Serial.readBytes(reciver,2); 
inShort[counter] = (short) reciver[0] | ((short) reciver[1]) << 8;
```